# How to use the copy constructor

Tags: java, constructor

```
class Circle {

  private double r;

  public Circle(double r) {
    this.r = r;
  }

  public void Circle(double r) {
  }

  double calCircumference() {
    return 2 * Math.PI * r;
  }

  public double calArea() {
    return Math.PI * r * r;
  }
}
```

How would i go about adding a copy constructor to the class Circle?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. What you can do is have the constructor take the class object type as a param, and then set values accordingly.

```
class Circle {
   private double r;

   public Circle(double r) {
    this.r = r;
   }

   // Copy constructor
   public Circle(Circle c) {
    this.r = c.r;
   }
}


// example of use case

Circle c1 = new c(5);   // initialize c1
Circle c2 = new c(c1);  // copy c1 to c2
c2.r = 3;
System.out.println(c1.r + " " ); // prints "5"
System.out.println(c2.r + " " ); // prints "3"
```

Comment: I would call it clone constructor, rather than copy constructor.

Comment: @c0der yes in java there are no such things as copy constructor, but there are clone constructor which act exactly like copy constructor

Comment: A copy constructor would be `this= c;`

Comment: assuming you mean this as in the object, yes

Answer (score 0):

Not doing your homework for you, but giving you a bit of hint:

the idea of a copy constructor is to create a **new** object based on an existing one; so that you could write:

```
Circle first = new Circle(1.0);
Circle second = new Circle(first);
```

The above already gives you the signature of your new constructor. And in order to understand what that other constructor has to do: step back and think: which properties does a Circle have; and how would you make another circle have the same properties?!

Beyond that: learn about the difference between constructors and normal methods. As this here:

```
 public void Circle(double r) {
 }
```

simply doesn't make *any* sense! (hint: constructors do not specify a return type!)